# listview not getting displayed

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to filter data from database and display filtered data into `listview` using `cursor`.  Unfortunately, the cursor is returned from the query isn't empty but the items not getting displayed in the activity.And moreover, there's no error being displayed in the logcat.

**My search_results.java:**

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search__results);
    lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String from = intent.getStringExtra("from");
    String to = intent.getStringExtra("to");
//    String date = intent.getStringExtra("date");
//    String clas = intent.getStringExtra("class");
        myrailway = new no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.myRailwayAdapter(this);
//        Cursor cursor = myrailway.getTrainDetails(from, to);
        String[] FROM = null;
        String[] TO = null;
        String[] TRAINNAME = null;
        String[] TRAINNO = null;
        String[] DEPART = null;
        String[] ARRIVAL = null;
        Cursor cursor = myrailway.getTrainDetails(from, to);
        if(cursor != null) {
            Log.e("ERROR","NON EMPTY CURSOR");
            int count = 0;
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                Log.e("ERROR","ENTERED LOOP");
                do {
                    String stnfrom = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.myRailwayAdapter.CONTACTS_COLUMN_STNFROM));
                    String stnto = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.myRailwayAdapter.CONTACTS_COLUMN_STNTO));
                    String trainname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.myRailwayAdapter.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME));
                    String trainno = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.myRailwayAdapter.CONTACTS_COLUMN_TRAINNUM));
                    String depart = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.myRailwayAdapter.CONTACTS_COLUMN_DEPART));
                    String arrival = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.myRailwayAdapter.CONTACTS_COLUMN_ARRIVAL));
                    FROM[count] = stnfrom;   Log.e("fr",stnfrom);
                    TO[count] = stnto;      Log.e("too",stnto);
                    TRAINNAME[count] = trainname;   Log.e("trainanme",trainname);
                    TRAINNO[count] = trainno;   Log.e("trainno",trainno);
                    DEPART[count] = depart;     Log.e("depart",depart);
                    ARRIVAL[count] = arrival;       Log.e("arrival",arrival);

                count = count + 1;
                cursor.close();
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            lviewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, FROM, TO, DEPART, ARRIVAL, TRAINNAME, TRAINNO);

            lview.setAdapter(lviewAdapter);
        }


    }
    else
        Log.e("ERROR","EMPTY CURSOR");

}
```

**My ListViewAdapter.java:**

```
   public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity context;
    String from[];
    String to[];
    String depart[];
    String arrival[];
    String trainname[];
    String trainno[];
    private no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.myRailwayAdapter myrailway;
    public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, String[] from, String[] to, String[] depart, String[] arrival, String[] trainname, String[] trainno) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.depart = depart;
        this.arrival = arrival;
        this.trainname = trainname;
        this.trainno = trainno;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return depart.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return depart[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        myrailway = new no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.myRailwayAdapter(this.context);
        Long recc= Long.valueOf(0);
        Cursor c= myrailway.getpass(trainname[i]);
        if(c!=null)
        {
            c.moveToFirst();
            recc=c.getLong(0);
        }
        return recc;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtfrom;
        TextView txtto;
        TextView txttrainno;
        TextView txttrainname;
        TextView txtdepart;
        TextView txtarrival;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (view == null)
        {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_items, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtfrom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.from);
            holder.txtto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.to);
            holder.txttrainno = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.trainno);
            holder.txttrainname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.trainname);
            holder.txtdepart = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.depart);
            holder.txtarrival = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.arrival);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtfrom.setText(from[position]);
        holder.txtto.setText(to[position]);
        holder.txttrainno.setText(trainno[position]);
        holder.txttrainname.setText(trainname[position]);
        holder.txtdepart.setText(depart[position]);
        holder.txtarrival.setText(arrival[position]);

        return view;
    }
}
```

**My search_results.xml:**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.Search_Results">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**My listview_items.xml:**

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow>
        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="0dip" android:layout_gravity="top"
            >
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/from"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/to"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:text=""
                    android:id="@+id/trainno"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                    android:gravity="left"/>
                <TextView
                    android:text=""
                    android:id="@+id/trainname"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                    android:gravity="left"/>

            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:text=""
                    android:id="@+id/depart"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                    android:gravity="left"/>
                <TextView
                    android:text=""
                    android:id="@+id/arrival"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                    android:gravity="left"/>

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/book"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="book"
            android:text="BOOK">

        </Button>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Now, the cursor isn't empty but the listview is not displayed by the listview adapter.
Can someone point out the error in the code??

Answer (score 1):

Please use this.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
  //here too;
    return depart.lenght;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
//there is error: repalce return null; with
    return depart[i];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    //change this too
    return depart[i].getId();
}
```

Comment: I added the required changes but still nothing is getting displayed. @user8773560

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 reasons that this may happen:

- You arrays are not filled with data/or filled with empty data and that the reason they are not presented. (less likely because you would receive a null pointer exception when you try to access a null location in the array)
- Your row layout doesn't show data parameters. (I will be
  on this reason, please show you row layout XML(listview_items.xml) so that we could check
  it)

**Check**: Make a check and print to the log all the data from 6 the arrays for every row before you set the data in the getView method.

Comment: Added my listview_items.xml in the question @Klevin Delimeta

Comment: Did you log your arrays before your getView method, but in your Adapter Class? Are they filled or empty?

Comment: And @user8773560 has a good point. Do that. And check again, please.

Comment: I tried to print the values contained in the strings. But it didn't log anything. And it didn't even print "ENTERED LOOP" that means its not entering the cursor loop. Can you review the code. I have made the changes according to the feedback  @Klevin Delimeta

Answer (score 0):

**getCount()**, **getItem()** and **getItemId()** are not set properly.

- getCount() should return the number of items in the arraylist;
- getItem() should return the item at the given position from the arraylist;
- getItemId() should return the internal id of the item if it has one, or the position of the item in the array or an hash number of the item.